# Implementing Elliptic curve point addition and multiplication in Python

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am learning Elliptic Curve cryptography, I have been working on an example from a book:
[image: example of problem with a=2,b=2, P=(5,1) and finding 2P]

I don't fully understand the line where the slope is calculated, specifically how **2^(-1) * 9= 13 mod 17**? I saw a post [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26003/elliptic-curve-point-addition)  that says to get the inverse with the Extended Euclidean algorithm.

I just don't see what 2^(-1) is the inverse for. What I understand from the EEA  is that for gcd(n, a) = (s*n + t*a) = 1 mod n, then t is our inverse for a. So if the EEA is really the answer to find my answer, what values do I use in the algorithm, and why? Or is there something that I am doing wrong in Python? (I am not as experienced in Python)

My code is in Python 3.11.1, here:

```
import math

def add(P, Q, a, p):
    if P != Q:
        S = ((Q[1] - P[1])/(Q[0] - P[0])) % p
    else:
        S = ((3 * P[0] ** 2 + a)/ 2 * P[1]) % p

    print("S is: "+ str(S))

    x = (pow(S, 2) - P[0] - Q[0]) % p
    y = (S*(P[0] - x)- P[1]) % p

    return [x, y]

def main():
    P = [5,1]
    R = add(P, P, 2, 17)
    print("R is: "+ str(R))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and my output is

```
S is: 4.5
R is: [10.25, 9.375]
```

My expected output from the example is:

```
S is: 13
R is [6, 3]
```

Comment: "I just don't see what 2^(-1) is the inverse for"; 2^(-1) is that number when, multiplied by 2 (modulo 17), results in 1.

Comment: @poncho How could I find that quickly? I don't fully see how we can use the EEA to find this.

Comment: @poncho Nevermind I see now, I did gcd(17,2) = 1*17+(-8)*2 and -8 mod 17 is 9 which is what we were looking for, this is correct right or is this a coincidence? Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: That's right.  IIRC, there are some built-ins in python that will do the work for you; one is pow(2, 17-2, 17) (which works because 17 is prime).  More generally, the inverse of x modulo a prime p is pow(x, p-2, p)

Comment: @poncho Oh thanks, that makes things easier!

Answer (score 3):

When there is $\displaystyle s=\frac{3{x_1}^2-1}{2y_1}$ in the context of Elliptic Curve, that's computed in a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)), that is a set with addition and multiplication such that usual rules of algebra apply, including a well-defined division by anything except $0$.

When further that's in the context of cryptography, the field is a [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field), noted $\mathbb F_q$, that has $q\ge2$ elements. Often, and in the context of the question and the rest of this answer, $q$ is a prime $p$, and then $\mathbb F_p$ is simply the integers modulo $p$, under addition and multiplication modulo $p$. When with $x,y,z\in\mathbb F_p$ we write some equality like $x=y\,z$, that really means this equality stands modulo $p$, that is $x\equiv y\,z\pmod p$, which by definition means: $p$ divides $y\,z-x$, where $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$.

For example, with $p=17$ as in the question, $10\cdot4\equiv6\pmod p$ because $p=17$ divides $10\cdot4-6=34$, thus when the context stipulates we are computing in $\mathbb F_p$ (which I assume in the following) it holds $10\cdot4=6$.

Division works just the same as in any field like the familiar reals $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$: the notation $\displaystyle z=\frac xy$ by definition means $y\ne0$ and $x=y\,z$. If follows $\displaystyle10=\frac 64$.

To make the calculation $\displaystyle z\gets\frac xy$, the first step is to check that $y\ne0$ (remember that's modulo $p$). Then for very small numbers like in the question, it's entirely feasible to search for $z$ until $x=y\,z$. It's also possible, and more common, to first compute $\displaystyle\frac 1y$, also noted $y^{-1}$, then compute $z\gets y^{-1}\,x$.

To compute $y^{-1}$ from $y\ne0$

- The textbook method is the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). Considering $y$ as an integer, we find integers $u$ and $v$ satisfying the Bezout equality $u\,p+v\,y=1$. It follows $v\bmod p$ is the desired $y^{-1}$. Since we do not need $u$, we need not compute it, and can use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Modular_integers). There are variants that work with non-negative integers at all steps, and others that need no modular reduction.
- Since $p$ is prime, by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), it holds $y^{p-1}=1$, thus $y^{-1}=y^{p-2}$. This tends to be slower, though.

It's pedagogically useful to implement the EEA, in particular because it works in any [finite ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_ring). However Python's [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) has been extended so that `pow(y, -1, p)` can be used to compute the modular inverse of `y` modulo `p` with many Python 3.8 and later. With even more versions, we can get away with `pow(y, p-2, p)`.

The question's `((3 * P[0] ** 2 + a)/ 2 * P[1]) % p` has two issues:

- Most importantly, `/` is used for division, when that's the operator for (an approximation of) the division in $\mathbb R$, yielding a floating point value. Operator `//` would at least yield an integer, but when there's a rounding that would not be the correct result.
- As an aside, precedence of operators is such that `* P[1]` is evaluated after and on the result of `/ 2`, thus if that was not for the earlier issue, it would be computed $\displaystyle\frac{3{x_1}^2-1}2\,y_1$ rather than the desired $\displaystyle\frac{3{x_1}^2-1}{2y_1}$.

A correct expression is `(3 * pow(P[0], 2, p) + a) * pow(2 * P[1], -1, p) % p`. The first `pow` is to compute the square with reduction modulo $p$ (this is strictly optional). The second `pow` is to compute the modular inverse of the denominator.

There are other functional issues with the code, including the other computation of the slope  and missing some cases; see the full addition algorithm in [sec1 §3.2.2](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.3.2.2).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I realized later that I should have known this from the ElGamal Encryption. But it's good to know now so thanks for explaining the math behind it to me!